# What is the difference between d/dt and dy/dt?

Tags: calculus

What is the difference between d/dt and dy/dt?  And when should either be used? I have seen both in my calculus class and don't know which to use in what context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\frac d{dt}$ is the differential *operator*. It doesn't signify any particular *value*, it's just meant to be applied to functions.

If you apply that operator to the function $y=y(t)$, then you get $$\frac d{dt}y = \frac{dy}{dt}$$

Or you can apply it to both sides of an equation relating functions like: $$f(t) = t^2+1 \\ \implies \frac d{dt}f(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(t^2+1) \\ \implies \frac{df(t)}{dt} = 2t$$

Comment: For the OP: A _function_ turns a number into another number; an _operator_ turns a function into another function.

Comment: No problem. :-)